# Update a subdocument contained in an array contained in a MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
Documents.update(
  {_id: Session.get("current_document_id")}, 
  {$push: {schema: {type: "text", size: size, name: name, label: label}}}
);
```

The above query is a Meteor collection, and 'Documents.update' maps to 'db.documents.update' in MongoDB documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/). With that query I can add a schema document inside the main document. Subdocuments are stored in an array:

```
Document:
  schema:
    array:
      {type: "text", size: 6, name: "first_name", label: "First name"},
      {type: "text", size: 6, name: "last_name", label: "Last name"}
```

I want to modify the name and size attributes of the subdocuments with this query:

```
Documents.update(
  {_id: Session.get("current_document_id"), 'schema' : "first_name"}, 
  {$push: {schema: {type: "text", size: 7, name: name, label: "First Name2"}}}
);
```

But that operation append a new object directly under schema and deletes the array:

```
Document:
  schema:
      {type: "text", size: 7, name: "first_name", label: "First Name2"}
```

How can I modify the query to change the attributes avoiding this issue? After the query I would like to have this document:

```
Document:
  schema:
    array:
      {type: "text", size: 7, name: "first_name", label: "First name2"},
      {type: "text", size: 6, name: "last_name", label: "Last name"}
```

Comment: schema points to an array of objects

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can update an existing array element using a `$set` operation that uses the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/) positional operator to identify the array element matched in the selector like this:

```js
Documents.update(
  {_id: Session.get("current_document_id"), 'schema.name': "first_name"}, 
  {$set: {'schema.$': {type: "text", size: 7, name: name, label: "First Name2"}}}
);
```

This will replace the matched `schema` element with the one included in the `$set` object.

If you only want to update individual fields of the targeted `schema` element, you can use dot notation. For example, to only update the `size` and `name` fields:

```js
Documents.update(
  {_id: Session.get("current_document_id"), 'schema.name': "first_name"}, 
  {$set: {'schema.$.size': 7, 'schema.$.name': name}}
);
```

Comment: Thanks it works but I am getting this error: https://gist.github.com/4243896. I will have a look later to find the cause. The error is not very explanatory.

Comment: @rtacconi Looks like the `$` positional operator isn't supported in meteor's minimongo: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/153

Comment: I also got the same problem . But I am trying to update the array using php code. In my code, I dont want to replace the array. But, I want to add a new row in the array

Comment: When I run this piece of code I'm getting an error:
"Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]". Can't figure out this one. I don't have id in the objects inside an array, what to do?

Comment: @aGit For Meteor, you need to put this in a server-defined method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796164/updating-item-in-array-with-unique-id

Comment: @JohnnyHK thx a lot. I've got it solved. But the solution here described i'm not updating only a field of the object in the array but the whole object.
If someone wants to update only one field of the object the modifier should go something like this:
var modifier = {$set: {'schema.$.name': content}};

Again, thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @aGit @JohnnyHK : how can you do the update on a certain element when you are inside an update hook and have the modifer: `modifier.$set.myArray.index.value = x` when index is the position and value is what i want to set? I tried `modifier.$set.myArray[index].value` but didn't work...

Comment: @Gobliins Would be best to post that as a separate question.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163399/meteor-collection-hooks-updating-element-on-a-position-in-array/52164412#52164412 And i found also a solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use arrayFilters with positional $[] operator

The example below from official mongodb documentation uses "elem" as the positional identifier

---

Consider a collection students2 with the following documents:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 80, "mean" : 75, "std" : 6 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 90, "std" : 4 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 6 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 90, "mean" : 75, "std" : 6 },
      { "grade" : 87, "mean" : 90, "std" : 3 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 4 }
   ]
}
```

To modify the value of the mean field for all elements in the grades array where the grade is greater than or equal to 85, use the positional $[] operator and arrayFilters:

```
db.students2.update(
   { },
   { $set: { "grades.$[elem].mean" : 100 } },
   {
     multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "elem.grade": { $gte: 85 } } ]
   }
)
```