# Updating item in array with unique ID

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've got a document structure like this:

```
Content {
  _id: "mongoId"
  Title: "Test",
  Age: "5",
  Peers: [{uniquePeer: "1", Name: "Testy Test", lastModified: "Never"}, {uniquePeer: "2", Name: "Test Tester", lastModified: "Never"}]

}
```

So `Peers` is an array that has a unique identifier. How can I update the lastModified of one of the sets in the array? According to mongodb I can only update a document using the document's unique ID, but that's at the top level. How can I say update this `lastModified` field in this set of `Peers` with a `uniquePeer` of 1 in this document?

Edit:

```
Content.update({"_id" : "mongoId", "Peers.uniquePeer" : "1"},{$set : {"Peers.$.lastModified" : "Now"}})
```

I still get a "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID."

Comment: I've added an update with the what you say is a duplicate. I can't seem to get it to work for mine.

Comment: In my code, my ```uniquePeer``` isn't an integer, it's a guid that has letters and numbers so I have to put a quote around it.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I've updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) for updating an array. Your code should look something like:

**server**

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'content.update.lastModified': function(contentId, peerId) {
    check(contentId, String);
    check(peerId, String);

    var selector = {_id : id, 'Peers.uniquePeer': peerId};
    var modifier = {$set: {'Peers.$.lastModified': 'Now'}};
    Content.update(selector, modifier);
  }
})
```

**client**

```js
Meteor.call('content.update.lastModified', contentId, peerId);
```

Note that this kind of operation needs to take place in a server-defined method because, as you found out, you can only update docs by id on the client.

Comment: Does the string *'Now'* magically get transformed by mongo to *new Date()*?

Comment: That would be cool, but no, I was just following his example.

Comment: That was my initial thought - "Did mongo just introduce a new trick?" So Joshua, you probably want `new Date()` there.