# Meteor/Mongo, push into an array inside an object inside an array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to teach myself Meteor and Mongo.  I have a particular insertion inside my Meteor method that is driving me nuts.

My document object looks like this:

```
{
    _id
    name: "name",
    stuff: {},
    array: [
        {
            id: 0,
            target:[
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "1"
                },{
                    id: 1,
                    name: "2"
                }
            ]
        },{
            id: 1,
            target:[
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "A"
                },{
                    id: 1,
                    name: "B"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

I am trying to add objects into the target array, which is inside an object inside the array-array.

I have tried a number of different approaches over a few days based on some things I have seen here on stack overflow.  The most recent attempt is:

```
Documents.update({_id: id, 'array.id': arrayId}, {$addToSet:{'array.$.target': objectToInsert}},{upsert: false, multi: false})
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I donot know the mongo query to do something like this but it can be done as below

```
let theArray=Document.findOne({_id:id}).array,
arrayOfIds=_.pluck(theArray,"id"),
index=_.indexOf(arrayOfIds,arrayId),
theArray[index].target.push(objectTobeInserted)
```

Now update the document with the modified array

```
Document.update({_id:id},{$set:{array:theArray})
```

If you donot understand _.pluck and _.indexOf, you can refer to [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org)

Comment: This worked, minus a couple of very minor syntactical errors.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this could be an issue with where you are doing the update. If this is on the client, then see here:

[Update an subdocument contained in an array contained in a MongoDB document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777097/update-an-subdocument-contained-in-an-array-contained-in-a-mongodb-document)

Solution is to move this to the server.

Also, you may want to look at the difference between $addToSet and $push here [MongoDb: Difference between $push/$addtoset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248556/mongodb-difference-between-push-addtoset)

If this is not on the client side and changing to push does not fix your issue, can you add to your question what the error is.