# meteor collection hooks updating element on a position in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection-hooks

i have this object:

```
card: { customFields [ { id, value }, {id , value } ... ] }
```

A customFields array is inside cards, which contans elements consisting of an id and a value.

Now i want to update a certain element inside of the array, which can be done by doing something like this:

```
  modifier.$set.customFields.0.value = x
```

but i have the number of the index only in a variable, so i tried:

```
const index = getTargetIndex();
modifier.$set.customFields[index].value = x
```

but it didn't work...

What do i have to add to the modifier.$set to update an element in this array?

Alternate Solution: i have the id of the element in the array if the update can be done on value by using the id.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
modifier.$set[`customFields.${  index  }.value`]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to do it using a second update:

```
update(selector, modifier, options, callback) {
  let i = 1;
  let val = 20;

  // The field in the array you want to modify
  let _modifier = {$set: {"customFields.$.value": val}}; 

  // The selector for main element and the array element
  let _selector = Object.assign(selector, {"customFields.id": i}); 

  // Update the array
  super.update(_selector, _modifier);

  // Continue with the actual update
  return super.update(selector, modifier, options, callback);
}
```

I'm assuming it's safe to call `super.update()` twice in the same hook.